# Why do my questions often get upvoted while my answers get downvoted?

Tags: support, reputation, downvotes, upvotes

I'm an average Stack Overflow user. I ask some questions and I get some upvotes. I also thought about answering other people's questions. I don't know why, but I get downvoted every time I do that.

Why?
I'm not really mad about anything, but I would like to know why, so I can avoid those mistakes that got people triggered.

In general, why do people downvote? Is it due to false information? Explaining, instead of putting code? Or are there people here, who just like being mean?

One thing that I can think of, is speaking with rude and offensive manners. Does being cold in meaning of being straight and not using Thanks or ... count as being offensive?

Examples:

1. I feel like I know why this one got down-voted. ([Does [ : ] create a copy of the list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74139015/does-create-a-copy-of-the-list/74139220#74139220)) I explained some stuff and provided a link to another question with the same stuff, instead of reporting as duplicate. I think this is due to me just not correcting the solution.
2. Like I got way to blown-out on writing [functional programming in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24949635/functional-programming-in-python/74238531#74238531), but somehow it got me downvoted.

In general I would like someone to look through my profile & tell me some of my mistakes. Right now I only had 3 downvotes, which is nothing, but I would like to fix this, so it won't happen again.

Comment: Not at all related; but it is super weird you start every post with "there!"

Comment: @Warcupine a bunch of greetings are silently removed from the starts of posts IIRC, so likely "Hello there!" being changed to "there!"

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine oh, that would make sense.

Comment: Your writing style could be related. Have a look at my edit on this question. Try to avoid excessive formatting, don't use `&` instead of _"and"_, and don't overuse `-`.

Comment: See my edits on your main site questions. There is still a lot of poor phrasing. But I expect downvotes were for bigger problems.

Comment: Related: *[Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/)*

Comment: Related: [Stack Overflow is not a forum](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/36818/would-you-recommend-stackexchange-sites-vs-other-types-of-forum/36828#36828)

Comment: The writing isn't bad. It just needs to be adjusted a little bit for this medium. For instance, there isn't any need for signalling, e.g., by using Internet slang.

Comment: "I'm an average Stack Overflow user" - bingo. In my experience in the way you explain something you often betray the core issue, you just need to identify it. You should be a contributor, not a user. Contributors put the needs of others above their own. I.E.: you do not apply poetic freedom to the way you write things, you keep it all business, neutral and to the point. Even if that bores you to tears. It probably is as simple as that, you're not doing anything horribly wrong.

Answer (score 14):

For [Does [ : ] create a copy of the list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74139015/does-create-a-copy-of-the-list/74139220#74139220):

- A question like this is 99% likely to have already been answered.  So, instead of trying to answer it, finding a dupe is preferable.
- Use concise, simple language to answer the question as expressly as you can.  There's no need to embellish on the answer.  Simply saying that "this does create a copy, here's a reference to the language specs to back that claim up" in *essence* would be all you need.

For [functional programming in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24949635/functional-programming-in-python/74238531#74238531):

- *Holy* wall of text.  That was a lot of unneeded background to get to your answer(s).
- You're...blatantly incorrect about there not being a return statement with lambdas, since the one-liner [presumes that you're returning the expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda).

For both:

- Your manner of typing is similar to a manner of speaking that is more casual.  It'd be best to tighten that up a *little* bit to semi-semi-professional.  If how you spoke was how you dressed in the office, you'd be encouraged to change out of a pair of sweats and into something that pairs alright with your favorite t-shirt.
- **Omit the greeting.**
- Focus on the question and deliver a concise answer.
- Search for duplicates before venturing into answering a question.

Comment: Note that first answer is answering a different question than one was asked, and I believe downvotes are mainly for that reason.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov:  Oh, I see what you mean.  The *title* got answered, but the *body* wasn't.

Answer (score 7):

Review of [Does [ : ] create a copy of the list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74139015/does-create-a-copy-of-the-list/74139220#74139220):

The answer *does not* answer the question at all and clearly indicates that author knows that. The question asks two things about "slice assignment" (does it perform copy and what its performance), while the answer is about unrelated (short of similar syntax) slicing. Couple other problems - the answer does not in any way try to address performance part of the question and indeed as you pointed answers duplicate question.

I think the downvotes are perfectly valid for answering a different question. Note that downvoting for answering a duplicate would be more questionable, but still likely as there is not much value in creating duplicate content.

Comment: They don't actually even say anything about a duplicate, they do put a link in the answer but don't say why.

Comment: @philipxy this question has "instead of reporting as duplicate" remark about that answer.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't disputing what you wrote. I was adding to the problems with the main site answer post. (Beyond the fact that it is a duplicate.)